# show that the set $\{M, M+1, \cdots, M+ 2\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor +2\}$ contains a quadratic non-residue to modulus $p$

Tags: number-theory

Let $M$ be an integer, and let $p$ be a odd  prime . Show that the set  $$ \{M+1,M+2,M+3,\cdots,M+ 2\lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor+2\}$$ contains a quadratic non-residue to modulus $ p$ for all primes $ p$

maybe can use this well know:
[Smallest quadratic nonresidue is less than square root plus one](https://number.subwiki.org/wiki/Smallest_quadratic_nonresidue_is_less_than_square_root_plus_one) An odd prime $p$,  $a$ is the smallest positive integer that is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$,then $a<1+\sqrt{p}$.

maybe can sove this problem?

Comment: What is the point of placing a bounty on a solved problem? Is anything unclear / to be explained in my solution?

Comment: sorry, 
I don't think you're going to be able to read this. Could you be more specific?and I bounty this problem hope can see clear solution or other methods to solve it,But  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We [know](https://number.subwiki.org/wiki/Smallest_quadratic_nonresidue_is_less_than_square_root_plus_one) that there is a quadratic non-residue $n$ with $2\le n<\sqrt p+1$. Multiplying $n$ by the appropriate power of $4$, we can find a quadratic non-resdiue, say $n'$, in the range $\frac12\sqrt p<n'<2\sqrt p$.

Consider the set 
  $$ S = \{Mn',(M+1)n',\dotsc,(M+2\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+2)n'\}\pmod p. $$
The "distance" in $\mathbb Z_p$ between any two consecutive elements of this set is $n'<2\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+2$, and there is no gap between the largest and the the smallest elements of the set since
  $$ (M+2\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+2)n' > Mn' + p. $$
It follows that every interval in $\mathbb Z_p$ of length $2\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+2$ contains at least one element of $S$. In particular, there is an element of $S$ contained in $\{M,M+1,\dotsc,M+2\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+2\}$. In other words, there are $x,y\in\{M,M+1,\ldots,M+2\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor+2\}$ such that $y\equiv n'x\pmod p$. Since $n'$ is a non-residue, so is (exactly) one of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Hello, Multiplying n by the appropriate power of 4,we can find a quadratic non-resdiue, say $n'?$, it means there exist $\delta$,such $4^{\delta} n=n'?$,such $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{p}<4^{\delta} n<2\sqrt{p}$.if so,How to sure there exist this $\delta?$

Comment: @functionsug: Let $\delta$ be the largest integer with $4^\delta n<2\sqrt p$. Then $4^{\delta+1} n>2\sqrt p$; that is, $4\cdot 4^\delta n>2\sqrt p$, showing that $4^\delta n>\frac12\sqrt p$. Thus, $\frac12\sqrt p< 4^\delta n<2\sqrt p$, and we let $n'=4^\delta n$.

Comment: @functionsug: informally, you just keep multiplying $n$ by $4$ till the resulting product hits the interval $(\frac12\sqrt p,2\sqrt p)$. You cannot jump over this interval since the right endpoint of the interval is 4 times larger than its left endpoint.

Comment: I can't understand why demand $n'<2\sqrt{p}$What's the point of this restriction? Thanks,

Comment: For the argument to go through, we want to ensure that there is a non-residue $n'$ in the interval $(\frac12\sqrt p,2\sqrt p)$. To this end, we multiply $n$ by $4$ till the resulting product is less than $2\sqrt p$. All these multiples of $n$ are quadratic non-residues, and the largest of them will land in the target interval $(\frac12\sqrt p,2\sqrt p)$. Try to work out a numerical example, such as $p=5003$, $n=3$.